# How to prevent the console window from automatically minimizing on debug?

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio is minimizing the console window every time I'm starting a debug session, which requires me to expand it again every time so I can see the debug output. How to I prevent this so that the window stays as it is?

Answer (score -1):

Few things you can try are:

**Check Console Settings in Visual Studio:**

Go to "Tools" > "Options" in Visual Studio.
Navigate to "Debugging" > "General".
Ensure that the option "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window" is unchecked. If it's checked, try unchecking it and see if it resolves the issue.
Check Code for Window Manipulation:

**Are there any commands or functions that might manipulate the console window?**

Such as calls to `ShowWindow()` with `SW_MINIMIZE` or similar commands. Make sure there are no unintended calls to minimize the console window.

**Disable Taskbar Auto-Hide:**

Sometimes, Windows may minimize windows automatically if the taskbar is set to auto-hide. Try disabling auto-hide for the taskbar and see if it resolves the issue.

**Try Different Debugging Options:**

In Visual Studio, try different debugging options such as "Start Debugging" (F5) or "Start Without Debugging" (Ctrl + F5) and see if the behavior persists with both options.

**Check Windows Event Viewer:**

Check the Windows Event Viewer for any system-level events or errors related to window manipulation that might provide insights into the issue.

**Update Visual Studio:**

Ensure that you are using the latest version of Visual Studio and that all updates and patches are applied. Sometimes, issues like this are resolved in newer versions or updates of Visual Studio.

**Reinstall Visual Studio:**

If the issue persists and none of the above solutions work, consider reinstalling Visual Studio to ensure that there are no corrupted or misconfigured settings causing the problem.